# Selenium web driver error of Uninitialized constant Selenium::Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After executing script i am getting error "`': uninitialized constant Selenium::Webdriver"

here is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class TC_Login < Test::Unit::TestCase


@driver = Selenium::Webdriver.for :firefox
@driver.get "http:test.com"


    def test_01
        login()
    end


    def login()
        content
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one minor typo in your code, it's not `Selenium::Webdriver`, but `Selenium::WebDriver` with capital `D`.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class TC_Login < Test::Unit::TestCase
  #@driver = Selenium::Webdriver.for :firefox, yours is Webdriver
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  @driver.get "http:test.com"
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that also didn't work, I have used @@driver  instead of @driver, and it works :)

Comment: @MilinAgrawal: Glad you made it working. However, using `@@` doesn't sound like the solution to fix `uninitialized constant Selenium::Webdriver`. Please post your new working code again. `@` is the instance variable of a class, `@@` is the Class variable, both should work?

Comment: require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

class TC_Login < Test::Unit::TestCase

@@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@@driver.get "http:test.com"

 def test_1
  login()
 end

 def login()
  Content
 end

end

Comment: @MilinAgrawal: So how did `@` not work? Same exception? As you can see, `WebDriver` fixed you original exception, not `@@`

Comment: for @ getting error : NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

[source](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#how-does-webdriver-drive-the-browser-compared-to-selenium-rc)

Answer (score 0):

Please close the class using **End**

Main thing is
@driver = Selenium::Webdriver.for :firefox

Try this

## @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

WedDriver **D** sholud be Capital letter